# Point root folder to blog.domain.com and subdirectory to domain.com possible?

Tags: apache

I have wordpress blog in root folder. and static website in a subfolder.

in apache config: root folder points to blog.mysite.com and subfolder points to mysite.com.

For both urls blog.domain.com and domain.com root folder files get executed.

I want subfolder files to execute for domain.com. and  root folder files to execute for blog.domain.com

Is it possible?

Comment: This would depend on what you can control with your hosting control panel, and doesn't have anything to do with WordPress. I suggest contacting your host.